# How do I enter jquery with the "Enter" key or Button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function that works fine if the user clicks the button assigned.  If the user hits the enter key I get an error.  Is there a way to trigger jquery code with either?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnAdd").click(function() {
        //execute from click or enter key
    });
});
```

Comment: By any chance are you using IE as your browser?

Comment: It's easy enough to add a [`keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) handler; but on what element do you want to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following assuming you're entering data in a textbox and trying to capture the enter key:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#textBox").live("click", function() {
        //if enter key is pressed
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                //click the button and go to next page
                $("#btnAdd").click();
        }               
  });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        //Enter button pressed
        runCode();
    }
});

$("#btnAdd").click(function() {
    runCode();
});
```

Hopefully this is usefull!